# MYSQL EVENT or Something else ? trying to track "clicks for links"

Tags: php, mysql

I've been all over this site and google, trying to wrap my head about a solution.

I've created a script that tracks Website traffic that we sell to our members, everything works great and show all the data we want. It will even track the conversions, correctly.

My current problem is - turning off the traffic to the record (member) whose traffic has been all delivered.

After reading some articles, it would seem prefect to run an event, but I can't seem  to figure this part out.

It also needs to run numerous times ...

Basically, I am not familiar with Events / Triggers and don't know which to do here

Example; Member has purchase 1000 clicks - all have been delivered, not change status to completed.

```
CREATE EVENT newEvent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 Minute
DO
UPDATE links SET status = 'completed' WHERE bought = '0';
```

Database Structure:

ID - Incremental

userid - members userid

bought - shows the remaining clicks

count - shows clicks delivered

pkgamount - stores the clicks bought

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure this oversimplifies things, but can't "all_delivered" be a column in one of your tables; 2 values (either 'yes' or 'no'), if value = 'yes', don't run traffic script?

Comment: We're not selling fake traffic, this is a service withing a Network Marketing Opportunity. We run facebook / google ads for our members!

Comment: Please show what you've tried. This isn't a free code-writing service, we're here to help you fix the problems in your code. If you can't even make an attempt, you need to hire a real programmer, you're selling fake programming.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob - Yes, that would work, but I need an event or trigger to change the "yes" "no" ... otherwise, we would be going through 1000's of records daily.

Comment: So write a `TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE` that does what you want.

Comment: Not looking for a hand out here @Barmar ... I am just not understand how to work with events / triggers. 

CREATE EVENT newEvent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 Minute
DO
UPDATE links SET status = 'completed' WHERE bought = '0';

Comment: Don't use an event, use a trigger.

Comment: is there a when to make this run each time to record is accessed by the script ?

Comment: An event runs based on time. A trigger runs when action is performed upon a table. Event = replacement for cron job, more or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the event scheduler, use a trigger that runs when updating the `links` table:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER link_completed
BEFORE UPDATE ON links
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.bought = 0
    THEN SET NEW.status = 'completed';
    END IF;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked without any hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do to create and run an event.  There's some non-intuitive monkey business with delimiters, and with turning on the event scheduler.

```
DELIMITER $$

SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON$$     -- required for event to execute but not create    

CREATE EVENT `Event1`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
COMMENT 'disable delivery when quota used up'
DO
    BEGIN
        UPDATE links SET status = 'completed' WHERE bought = '0';
    END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Please note! You may want to say `WHERE bought <= 0` so that you can correctly use an index on your `bought` column and so you set the status correctly if a particular record falls below zero.

If I were you I'd use this statement.

```
        UPDATE links SET status = 'completed', bought = 0 WHERE bought <= 0;
```